# Android - Take picture without preview

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am trying to take a picture without preview, immediately when my application starts running and after that to save the picture in new folder - "pictures123", in the root folder.
Could someone please tell me what's wrong in my code?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pictures123/");

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }

    Camera camera = Camera.open(0);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    SurfaceView mview = new SurfaceView(getBaseContext());
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
    camera.startPreview();
    camera.takePicture(null,null,photoCallback);
    camera.stopPreview();
}

Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/pictures123");
            File file = new File (myDir, "pic1.jpeg");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();

    }
};
```

permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take pictures from the camera without preview when my app starts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684553/how-to-take-pictures-from-the-camera-without-preview-when-my-app-starts)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't take a picture without a preview, but you don't have to show the preview on screen.  You can direct the output to a SurfaceTexture instead (API 11+).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462360/android-use-camera-without-surfaceview-or-textureview/22468306#22468306) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you are calling takePicture immediately after startPreview which actually takes time to complete its setup. So adding a delay between those two could temporarily fix this issue, [look here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824087/strange-behaviour-with-camera-and-surfaceview/20825344#20825344).

Comment: With `camera.setPreviewDisplay(null)`, no delay will help (_well, there exist some devices that allow such ricks_). Also note, that _delay_ cannot be a simple `Sleep()` call here and there. The flow of camera initialization involves some callbacks and requires timely response to these. E.g. one cannot use SurfaceHolder before the `SurfaceView` has called `SurfaceCreated()` on its listener.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to take a picture without preview. You should read the Android online reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture.

Note:
This method is only valid when preview is active (after startPreview()). Preview will be stopped after the image is taken; callers must call startPreview() again if they want to re-start preview or take more pictures. This should not be called between start() and stop().

Comment: Are you sure that it's impossible to take a picture without preview? i know an application that do this - "gotya!". this app takes a picture if someone tried to unlock the device with an incorrect password.

Comment: I think it just hided the preview. For example, you can add a customized view over SurfaceView.