# Hide preview screen after picture captured in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, camera

Please tell me how can I hide preview screen after I take picture using Camera. Like, I have button on screen that open camera, then I do take picture, and finally image gets displayed in my app. After I take photo it shows me picture and ask me for "OK"  or "RETRY" (basically preview screen), can anyone tell me how can I hide it.? It is Xamarin.Forms project.
Thank You

Comment: You can't achieve it on application layer. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754597/android-take-picture-without-preview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/taking-picture-from-camera-without-preview).